# ifdown in cron bash script fails to run

Tags: networking, cron, reboot, interface

I have a script that is run when a server (Ubuntu 14.04) boots up using @reboot in crontab (Under the root user)

```
@reboot /bin/bash /root/init.sh >> /var/logs/vminit.log
```

The script runs a number of things, but when it reaches this line

```
ifdown eth1
```

The script exits, and `ifdown` does not run. (Running `ifconfig` still shows eth1 in the output) Enabling Verbose mode on `ifdown` returns nothing too.

If I manually run the script myself, it runs as expected.

I wrote a test script just to rule out any issues with `init.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'one'
ifdown eth1
echo 'two'
```

If I run it manually, I get this output (which is expected)

```
one
<DHCP Client info>
two
```

If I place this test script into the crontab to be run with `@reboot`, I get the same results as `init.sh`, and the output is

```
one
```

I've tested by running the cron at an exact time (Example: `25 14 * * *`) to see if it's something with `@reboot', but no luck.

I've also tried delaying the script from running after boot incase something was blocking ifdown from running

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 60; /bin/bash /root/init.sh >> /var/log/vminit.log
```

A few notes: 
- Eth1 is an active interface, prior to running ifdown the script makes a call out of eth1 to grab a file successfully.
- The script is run as root
- Permissions with the script (and log) are fine. 
- Running `init.sh` or the test script manually runs as expected.

Comment: **1.** Does the script (and `ifdown`) hang or end prematurely? (Do you see it in `ps -ef`?) It should hang if your script does not continue. ------ **2.** Try to use the verbose switch to get more information: `ifdown -v eth1` ------ **3.** Does it fail if you manually restart `cron`? Try `sudo service cron stop && sudo service cron start` ------ **4.** What are the exported environment variables in the working and non-working case? Store the output of `export`. If the non-working case is missing some variables which could be important, try to set them in your script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really I don't know why `ifdown` doesn't work with crontab.

Anyway, I faced the same situation a long time ago and have a workaround solution, hope this will help you.

Replace

```
ifdown eth1
```

with

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth1 down 1> /dev/null
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I logged in to post that I found the cause and you've answered it for me! Turns out that the default PATH variable is different for crons and a logged in user (for an out the box install). Setting the full path `/sbin/ifconfig` then worked. Strange that it didn't return any errors in the output/log though.

Comment: @adam0345 That's good

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when I use `ifup` or `ifdown` in a cron job:

1. First of all, be sure that `ifupdown` is installed:

   ```
   apt-get install ifupdown
   ```
2. Find `ifdown` location:

   ```
   which ifdown
   ```
3. Refer to `ifdown` with absolute path:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo 'one'
   /sbin/ifdown eth1
   echo 'two'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use wpa_cli as a cron job you need to provide the full path like so:

```
/sbin/wpa_cli -i eth1 reconfigure
```